# hottowel undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, hottowel

This is my first experience using Node.js

I am following this tutorial: http://www.johnpapa.net/get-up-and-running-with-node-and-visual-studio/

I am using Cmder as my command prompt.

I have all components installed and I can view the versions of:
Node
npm
bower
yeoman
gulp
grunt

When I try to build the app using: gulp serve-dev --sync This is the output:

```
F:\Projects\myapp
λ gulp serve-dev --sync
[04:18:21] Using gulpfile F:\Projects\myapp\gulpfile.js
[04:18:21] Starting 'wiredep'...
[04:18:21] Wiring the bower dependencies into the html
[04:18:21] Starting 'clean-styles'...
[04:18:21] Cleaning: ./.tmp/**/*.css,./build/styles/**/*.css
[04:18:21] Starting 'clean-code'...
[04:18:21] Cleaning: ./.tmp/**/*.js,./build/js/**/*.js,./build/**/*.html
[04:18:21] Finished 'clean-styles' after 32 ms
[04:18:21] Starting 'styles'...
[04:18:21] Compiling Less --> CSS
[04:18:22] Finished 'clean-code' after 625 ms
[04:18:22] Starting 'templatecache'...
[04:18:22] Creating an AngularJS $templateCache
F:\Projects\myapp\node_modules\gulp-less\index.js:68
    }).done(undefined, cb);
       ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at DestroyableTransform._transform (F:\Projects\myapp\node_modules\gulp-less\index.js:68:8)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (F:\Projects\myapp\node_modules\gulp-less\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:184:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (F:\Projects\myapp\node_modules\gulp-less\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:172:12)
    at doWrite (F:\Projects\myapp\node_modules\gulp-less\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:237:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (F:\Projects\myapp\node_modules\gulp-less\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:227:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (F:\Projects\myapp\node_modules\gulp-less\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:194:11)
    at write (F:\Projects\myapp\node_modules\gulp-plumber\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:623:24)
    at flow (F:\Projects\myapp\node_modules\gulp-plumber\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:632:7)
    at DestroyableTransform.pipeOnReadable (F:\Projects\myapp\node_modules\gulp-plumber\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:664:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:129:20)
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: There was a problem with the gulp-less build. https://github.com/plus3network/gulp-less/issues/140

Comment: ^^ That should be an answer, not just a comment. ^^

Comment: @DavidKnipe But it would be a link-only answer.

Comment: @Spencer Wieczorek Are those not allowed? I really don't undersatnd the reasoning behind some of the rules on stackoverflow/stackexchange.

Comment: @DavidKnipe It's because links can become invalid over time. Adding the information necessary from the link prevents that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experienced the same issue.
Changing the versions of devDependencies in **package.json** file helped. Set the versions like this:

```
"gulp-less": "^3.0.0",
```

and

```
"gulp-ng-annotate": "^0.5.2",
```

And run `npm update`

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with the gulp-less build. https://github.com/plus3network/gulp-less/issues/140